# Как преобразовать кортеж данных в строки, построчно с добавлением нового разделителя?

Tags: python

Необходимо преобразовать кортеж данных в строки. Ответ должен быть:

```
one = 1
two = 2
three = 3
four = 4
```

```
КОД:

x = {"one": 1, "two": 2,"three": 3, "four": 4}


lst = list(x.items())


#это условие не помогает: a = '\n'.join(map('='.join(lst)))


print(lst)
```

Результат:

```
[('one', 1), ('two', 2), ('three', 3), ('four', 4)]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
x = {"one": 1, "two": 2,"three": 3, "four": 4}

res = '\n'.join(f"{a} = {b}" for a,b in x.items())

print(res)
```

Answer (score 2):

Это не кортеж, а словарь. Как вариант:

```
x = {"one": 1, "two": 2,"three": 3, "four": 4}

print(*[f'{k} = {x[k]}' for k in x], sep='\n')
```

Answer (score -4):

УЗНАЛ ОТВЕТ:

```
x = {"one": 1, "two": 2,"three": 3, "four": 4}

string = "\n".join([f"{key} = {value}" for key, value in x.items()])

print(string)
```

Comment: чем это отличается от уже данных вам ответов кроме имен переменных? и квадратные скобки - необязательны

Comment: По сути совпадает с ответом от @Danis